# Use OnLongPress and OnPress differently in flutter datatable?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to do different actions on a DataTable object depending on LongPress vs ShortPress?

ShortPress -- Present details (read only),
LongPress -- Present details (read-write).

I do

```
    await Navigator.push(
        context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Page2(dataRow, editMode)));
```

from the DataTable's `OnSelectChanged`,but I don't know how to set "editmode" based on a longPress vs a shortPress (or double-tap)...

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `GestureDetector` to every DataCell may not be the best solution but it should work

```
DataTable(columns: [
    DataColumn(
      label: Text("Name"),
    ),
    DataColumn(
      label: Text("Age"),
    ),
    DataColumn(
      label: Text("Year"),
    ),
  ], rows: [
    DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(
        GestureDetector(
          child: Text("Ross"),
          onTap: () {
            print('Tap');
          },
          onLongPress: () {
            print('Long Press');
          },
        ),
      ),
      DataCell(
        GestureDetector(
          child: Text("28"),
          onTap: () {
            print('Tap');
          },
          onLongPress: () {
            print('Long Press');
          },
        ),
      ),
      DataCell(
        GestureDetector(
          child: Text("2003"),
          onTap: () {
            print('Tap');
          },
          onLongPress: () {
            print('Long Press');
          },
        ),
      ),
    ]),
  ]);
}
```